# How do I wipe my MB Air's drive and start fresh?

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, upgrade, macbook-pro

I want to return my Air to the original factory settings, to the way it was before I added all kinds of  junk to the solid state drive.

I'm running Snow Leopard. So after I wipe it clean, I plan to go to the App Store and buy Lion.

Comment: The user manual for each Mac has details for your shipping system. Put your serial number in at http://support.apple.com/manuals/# and follow the steps for reinstallation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you bought a pre-Lion Macbook Air, it should have shipped with a system restore USB drive. This is exactly the scenario for which it exists: restoring your system to factory condition. Back up all your data, so you can keep what you want. Then, plug in the restore drive, and hold down the option key (<kbd>⌥</kbd>) when you boot. Select the restore drive, and follow the instructions to install a clean install of Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 3):

If you're planning on immediately upgrading to Lion, you could save some time by downloading Lion first, and [making your own USB installer](http://www.macworld.com/article/161069/2011/07/make_a_bootable_lion_installer.html). You can still wipe the drive clean first, but this way you're only doing 1 OS install instead of 2.